.databrickscfg does not contain account profiles
I am trying to generate a integration with databricks CLI and Posit Workbench,but when I run :
databricks account custom-app-integration \
 create --json '{"name":"posit-workbench", "redirect_urls":["https://<server-address/oauth_redirect_callback"], "scopes":["all-apis","offline_access"]}'

I get the error :
Error: /home/<user>/.databrickscfg does not contain account profiles

.databrickscfg :
[DEFAULT]
host       = https://<SERVER_ADDRESS>
token      = TOKEN

Permissions for the file:
-rw------- 1 <user> domain^users 126 May 22 21:32 .databrickscfg

The other commands are running. For example if I run:
databricks clusters list -p DEFAULT

I get the correct list of all avaiable clusters for this user.
databricks auth env --profile DEFAULT
{
  "env": {
    "DATABRICKS_AUTH_TYPE": "pat",
    "DATABRICKS_CONFIG_PROFILE": "DEFAULT",
    "DATABRICKS_HOST": "https://<server-address>",
    "DATABRICKS_TOKEN": "token"
  }
}

What am I doing wrong?
Thank you in advance !

databicks cli version: Databricks CLI v0.219.0

updated databricks CLI to v0.220.0 - still the same problem

Add this to your .databrickscfg:
[ACCOUNT]
host = https://accounts.azuredatabricks.net/
account_id = [redacted]

You can get your account id from the account console.
databricks account console
After doing that, you should be able to use the account profile like so:
databricks account groups list --profile ACCOUNT


To get the account id I used databricks current-user me in terminal and I got the the account id from the field externalId. When I add it like you said and try to execute "databricks account groups list --profile ACCOUNT" I get "Error: invalid Databricks Account configuration".

That's not your databricks account id - that's the application id of your user principal. I don't know of a way to programmatically get the account id. If you have the appropriate level of admin rights, you can go to the account console and view it there.

I was trying to use an AWS integration in a AZURE environment.
Ref: https://docs.posit.co/ide/server-pro/integration/databricks.html
The custom-app-integration as the following is for AWS environment:
databricks account custom-app-integration  create --json '{"name":"posit-workbench", "redirect_urls":["https://<server-address/oauth_redirect_callback"], "scopes":["all-apis","offline_access"]}'

Azure environment is integrated using Microsoft Entra.
